# Migrate only new projects from Crashlytics to Fabric

Tags: android, ios, migration, crashlytics

Is it possible to only migrate new projects from Crashlytics to Fabric and leave the existing projects as it is ?

Or is this not possible and will all projects new and old migrated to Fabric?

Comment: What the problem in moving all projects to fabrics? I guess nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Fabric here. Absolutely possible. Once you upgrade to Fabric your original Crashlytics apps will continue to work normally and you can view them via your fabric.io dashboard. You can then migrate apps to the updated Fabric SDKs at your convenience.

Comment: thanks! one question. How long can we use the outdated Crashlytics SDK (API) until it gets to deprecated status ? Just so i know how much of a hurry i have to be in. And to know for how long my existing apps will stil function correctly.

Comment: No timeline for deprecation of the original Crashlytics SDK. If that's something we plan to do, we'll make sure to give everyone a lot of notice.